# Razor Language Services extension is crashing VS2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2017, razor-language-services

I recently updated my VS 2017 to address git vulnerability issue and now it seems like it keeps crashing when I build my solution from the command line -- if I have a Razor view open in the editor.  It restarts VS2017 with a yellow bar:

```
A Previous session terminated unexpectedly. Disabling extension 'Razor Language Services 15.3.30918' might help prevent similar issues.  Disable this extension...
```

I tried disabling the extension but then it can't open my Razor views because it doesn't have Razor available.  So I tried uninstalling it, which also removed ASP.net.  I reinstalled everything but it continues to give me the same error.

If I close the razor view before building it won't crash.

VS2017 is version: 15.3.3.  Core Razor Language Services is version 1.0.

Update:  problem resolved by removing all existing installations of VS2017 and re-installing updated version 15.7.3 and have had no further problems with open razor views since then.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44305161/2157640
Removing the extension and repairing the VS installation should work. Then, Razor Language Services may be installed as a feature from Tools > Get Tools and Features...

Comment: Thanks @Palec... this is more or less what I ended up doing.  I removed my existing installations of Visual Studio and installed a fresh, updated version and haven't seen the problem since :)

Comment: Maybe the question should be closed as a duplicate of the other one, then, in order not to waste time of people looking for questions to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduced VS 2017 IDE interactivity in MVC 5 Razor views in 2015 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305161/reduced-vs-2017-ide-interactivity-in-mvc-5-razor-views-in-2015-project)